# Cannot create database by using rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm

I have just faced to problem about using rails db:migrate. The below images show exactly what problem I have faced. [[This is the error when I run command `rails db:migrate`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W5tA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q696O.png)

And this is my code:

```
class CreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :admins do |t|

      t.string :email, limit: 50
      t.string :encrypted_password, limit: 100
      t.integer :sign_in_count, default: 0
      t.string :hashid1, limit: 100
      t.string :hashid2, limit: 100
      t.string :encrypted_fullname_vi, limit: 100
      t.string :encrypted_fullname_en, limit: 100
      t.string :encrypted_birthday, limit: 100
      t.string :encrypted_address, limit: 100
      t.string :nickname
      t.json :image_json
      t.integer :show_avatar, limit: 1, default: 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I tried many ways in this forum but it was still ineffective. How can I fix this?

Here are the details about my environment:
Ruby: 3.1.4
Rails: 7.0.8
Migration: 7.0

Comment: current_schemas function is in postrgresql, not in mysql. As if you tried to use postgresql setting in your ORM with a mysql connection.

Comment: Hmm, do you know how can I fix it? Because I just use MySQL2 for my project. I do not use PostgreSQL.

Comment: Nope, I do not know that - this is somethung you set in your ORM, nothing to do with mysql or postgresql.

Comment: Please add your database.yml

Comment: did you already run `rails db:create`? ... just checking... sorry if it's obvious

Comment: You quite probably have your database misconfigured in rails. I second the request for your `database.yml`

Comment: Hmm... In database.yml, I already added databases for development, test environment. I also run `rails db:create`. But it is not working.

Comment: I have checked in localhost, 2 databases were added successfully. I just don't understand why does the error occur when I run `rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've created your Rails project with the Postgres flag but then you're using the MySQL2 gem and/or connecting to a MySQL database.

If you want to solve it, you can either switch to a Postgres database or use the MySQL2 gem and re-run your model scaffolding.

You can run `bin/rails db:drop db:create` to restart afresh.

Comment: So great. I will try it and respond later. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, when I created my Rails app, I run `rails new MyRailsApp -d mysql`. This flag added gem mysql2 into Gemfile.

Comment: Okay, so it's normal then. Maybe you can try to check which mysql version you have. The 8th version is a breaking change and has a lot of new features.

Comment: Confirmed your solutions working fine. Thanks a lot!